# override wedevs-dokan-plugin template file from theme wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using the `wedevs-dokan-plugin` ([wedevs.com/dokan](http://wedevs.com/dokan/)) for a WordPress frontend user store, which allows sellers to manage their store from the frontend.
I want to override one of the template files of this plugin. The file which I want to override is located at:

```
plugins/wedevs-dokan-plugin/templates/product-edit.php
```

And to override this file, I copied the file and made some changes, putting this new file in the theme directory like this:

```
themes/mytheme/wedevs-dokan-plugin/product-edit.php
```

But this isn't working for me. After that I also tried:

```
themes/mytheme/wedevs-dokan-plugin/templates/product-edit.php
```

But that's also not working.

Is there any way to override the plugin files from within a WordPress theme?

Answer (score 3):

```
themes/mytheme/wedevs-dokan-plugin/product-edit.php
```

Instead of "wedevs-dokan-plugin" the directory name should be "dokan" and you can only edit the "templates" directory files of this plugin.

So, the new directory will look like these.

```
themes/mytheme/dokan/store.php
themes/mytheme/dokan/dashboard/dashboard.php
```

Thanks